# Academic reference for employment

Tags: recommendation-letter, reference-request

If a Professor has explicitly stated that he is open to being a reference for a summer scholarship application, would it be reasonable to assume that he would be alright with the same candidate citing him as a reference for future employment?

Comment: It is at least likely, but is there any reason not to confirm this with a quick email? It's generally a bad idea not to let your references know that they might get a call.

Comment: I tell my students, "You have to let me know before you give my name as a reference.  Otherwise, I might think they're trying to sell me something and blow them off."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, you should make no assumptions about what other people think, whatever we are talking about. People are just too very different.

I think that you should ask your professor, simply as that.

And good luck for you!